# Dynamic LINQ. No property or field 'FieldName' exists in type 'ClassName'

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamic-linq, xpo

My LINQ query is as follows

```
Dim Query = From t In New XPQuery(Of xUser)(Xpo.Session.DefaultSession)
.Where("Name=John").Select("new (Name as FirstName)")
```

Unfortunately i get the error `No property or field 'John' exists in type 'xUser'`

Of course no such property exists in my xUser class, but hot can i fix that?

After reading within the DynamicLinq Class i found this function

```
Function FindPropertyOrField(ByVal type As Type, ByVal memberName As String, ByVal staticAccess As Boolean) As MemberInfo
    Dim flags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly Or _
        If(staticAccess, BindingFlags.Static, BindingFlags.Instance)
    For Each t As Type In SelfAndBaseTypes(Type)
        Dim members As MemberInfo() = t.FindMembers(MemberTypes.Property Or MemberTypes.Field, _
            flags, type.FilterNameIgnoreCase, memberName)
        If members.Length <> 0 Then Return members(0)
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

How can i edit my "faulty" query? What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What if you try to set 'John' as an parameter instead of directly in the string?

Comment: @ Wouter de Kort It works! Could you post it as an answer please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to set 'John' as a parameter instead of directly in the string.

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) you can find some documentation which shows this. It would look like `.Where("Name=@0", "John")`

Answer (score 4):

It should be `.Where("Name='John'")` (quotes around the string).

Alternatively, you can use a parameter: `.Where("Name=@0", "John")`